# Retrieving specific hash key values from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, design-patterns, hash, computer-science

All,

I was wondering if anyone knew a better patten than:

```
array_of_hashes.map { |hash_from_array| hash_from_array[:key] }
```

for retrieving an array of values with a specific key from an array of hashes containing that key.

Comment: looks fine to me, although the hash_from_array variable naming is a little bit of overkill.  "h" would probably do it.

Comment: heh, was mealy to improve the readability of the example. :)

Comment: a very direct solution - I like it

Comment: don't forget to compact the final array (result) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ruby code perspective, the `map` is pretty elegant and straightforward.

From the algorithmic point of view (to address the computer-science tag), it seems a solution to this problem cannot be better than going through the whole array once (i.e. a `map` here), so it will take as much time as to process each hash in the array.

@Vlad: Compacting the returned array depends on what will be done with the array, right? :-)